# How to conditionally create pandas column from other column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    word              start  stop speaker
0  but that's alright  2.72  3.47  2
1       we'll have to  8.43  9.07  1
2           okay sure  9.19 11.01  2
3               what? 11.02 12.00  1
4             I agree 12.01 14.00  2
5      but i disagree 14.01 17.00  2
6          thats fine 17.01 19.00  1
7     however you are 19.01 22.00  1
8           like this 22.01 24.00  1
9                 and 24.01 25.00  1
```

I want to create two new columns, df.speaker_1 and df.speaker_2. When df.speaker == 2, I want df.speaker_2 to contain the values of df.word. When df.speaker != 2, I want it to contain an empty string. The same will be repeated for the other speaker value. It should look as below:

```
    word        start  stop speaker   speaker_2            speaker_1
0  but that's alright  2.72  3.47  2  but that's alright   
1       we'll have to  8.43  9.07  1                       we'll have to
2           okay sure  9.19 11.01  2  okay sure
3               what? 11.02 12.00  1                       what?
4             I agree 12.01 14.00  2  I agree
5      but i disagree 14.01 17.00  2  but i disagree
6          thats fine 17.01 19.00  1                       thats fine
7     however you are 19.01 22.00  1                       however you are
8           like this 22.01 24.00  1                       like this
9                 and 24.01 25.00  1                       and
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy values from your column `word` then replace with empty strings as needed:

```
df['speaker_1'] = df['word']
df['speaker_2'] = df['word']

df.loc[df['speaker'] != 1, 'speaker_1'] = ''
df.loc[df['speaker'] != 2, 'speaker_2'] = ''
```

Alternatively, you could use `apply`, but I find this is more straightforward in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pd.DataFrame.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask):

```
df['speaker_1'] = df.word.mask(df.speaker!=1, '')
df['speaker_2'] = df.word.mask(df.speaker!=2, '')

#                  word  start  ...        speaker_1           speaker_2
# 0  but that's alright   2.72  ...                   but that's alright
# 1       we'll have to   8.43  ...    we'll have to                    
# 2           okay sure   9.19  ...                            okay sure
# 3               what?  11.02  ...            what?                    
# 4             I agree  12.01  ...                              I agree
# 5      but i disagree  14.01  ...                       but i disagree
# 6          thats fine  17.01  ...       thats fine                    
# 7     however you are  19.01  ...  however you are                    
# 8           like this  22.01  ...        like this                    
# 9                 and  24.01  ...              and
```